# Hide Menu Unless Logged In

Tags: menus, navigation

I have one menu that I created called "Main Menu" and only want to show it to users that are logged in. I have only been able to find plugins that allow me to show/hide individual menu items, but not the entire menu. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the ability to either edit the theme or child theme, in the file where the menu is called (probably *header.php*), use something like this:

```
<?php
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) :
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'header-nav',
            'menu_id'        => 'header-menu',
        ) );
    endif;
?>
```

That'll be the preferred option because it won't load the navigation at all, so even someone savvy enough to look at the source code/developer console won't see it.

If you don't have the ability to edit the theme/child theme files, then you can do it using CSS:

```
#site-navigation {
    display:none;
}
body.logged-in #site-navigation{
    display:block;
}
```

A few notes, the CSS above addresses the `<nav>` tag for a site I've recently started building, you'll have to look at your source code/developer console and identify which element/container to add `display:none;` to.  The important part is that WordPress adds the `.logged-in` class to the body tag, specifically to allow us to write different CSS/js rules/functions depending on users being logged in.

Like I said though, the CSS isn't the preferred option if what you're after is preventing users that aren't logged in from being able to locate items with a menu - for that, you'd want to use the conditional check at the top.

**Addendum**
I should also add the you can add an `else` into the conditional statement and load a different menu, or a login link...

```
<?php
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) :
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'header-nav',
            'menu_id'        => 'header-menu',
        ) );
    else :
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'header-nav-notloggedin',
            'menu_id'        => 'header-menu-notloggedin',
        ) );
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the thorough response. Do I need to change "header-nav" or "header-menu" to something else or will those work as is? The theme menu location I'm using is Primary Menu and my menu is called Main Menu. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll need to change them to match the theme.  My guess would be: `'theme_location' => 'primary-menu'`.  You should check in the theme and locate where the menus are registered to ensure that matches.  The `menu_id` can actually be set in the example above, that's where you establish what the ID of the `<ul>` element is, so you don't need to match it.  In your theme there's be a place that has a 'register_nav_menus()' function, locate that and see what they set as location for the 'Primary Menu'.

Comment: Actually, if you look in your header.php file, you'll see what's already there - just take what's there, replace the `wp_nav_menu()` in the code I gave you and then paste my code in it's place.